# Encountering an issue with AWS SES (Simple Email Service)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

In our application, we are encountering an issue with AWS SES (Simple Email Service), which is the email delivery service we use. The specific problem we are facing with AWS SES is as follows:

### **Scenario 1:** Sending a mail with a UUID to `user1` and `user2`

**Mail content:**

```
    Welcome!

    Before login your account, you need to verify your new email for security purpose. just click the verify link below:

    Verify Email

    If the button above does not work, copy and paste this link into your browser

    https://ourwebsite/successmail/724ce3ec-2bc5-4bcd-9b9a-c5dca1eb0794

    If you have any questions, feel free to reply to this email.

    Thanks
```

In the mentioned mail content, we include a UUID while sending the mail.

**Expected Outcome:** The mail should be delivered to both `user1` and `user2`.

**Actual Result:** The mail is delivered to `user1` but not to `user2`.

### **Scenario 2:** Sending a mail without a UUID to `user1` and `user2`

**Mail content:**

```
    Welcome!

    Before login your account, you need to verify your new email for security purpose. just click the verify link below:

    Verify Email

    If the button above does not work, copy and paste this link into your browser

    https://ourwebsite/successmail/

    If you have any questions, feel free to reply to this email.

 

    Thanks
```

In the mentioned mail content, we have removed the UUID and sent the mail.

**Expected Outcome:** The mail should be delivered to both `user1` and `user2`.

**Actual Result:** The mail is delivered to both `user1` and `user2`.

**Note:** In AWS notifications for all mails, we are consistently receiving notifications of type "Delivery."

Typically, a mail with a UUID should be delivered to all users. However, this is not happening in our case. We kindly request your assistance in resolving this issue.

---

> Both users (user1 and user2) are in same domain

---

**Issue:**

In our application, we have implemented a functionality where a mail containing a universally unique identifier (UUID) should be delivered to all users. However, we are currently experiencing a problem where this is not occurring as expected. We kindly seek your assistance in resolving this issue with the AWS SES service.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If the e-mail is in fact delivered, then it should be indicated by the logs provided by SES; I am not sure where or **how much** SES is logging, and I have not used it for some time. But ideally they should be logging everything (E.g. full log messages with response codes) for debugging purposes, and not make assumptions about what their users understand about e-mail. Etc.

If the status is indeed correct, and as you mention, the e-mail has been "delivered", then this should indicate that the receiving mail server accepted the e-mail; it can be hard to tell what it actually did with the e-mail after accepting it without corresponding with the administrator of said service.

Based on the fact that simply removing the UUID changes the delivery, perhaps there is some filtering going on? In that case it should go to the spam folder, and users need to manually mark it as "not spam" – maybe the mail server admin can check that the message was not quarantined by mistake, depending on the service they use.

It could be the receiving mail server or the individual users have anti-spam policies that prevent delivery. E.g. In my company I have to log in to Microsoft and check the quarantine area for false positives that needs to be manually released to the users. The users seem to have no knowledge that this is going on, server-side, before some messages are delivered.

Some companies don't have anyone that does that, and pretty much just leave the spam policies after configuring them once or maybe not at all, which causes some mails to be silently lost. It's probably best not to have server-side spam filtering at all if there is no mail admin, and ultimately just leave it to the individual users.

Comment: Thanks for providing additional context. In our case, both users are using the same domain and mail server, and we have already checked the spam folders, but unfortunately, we haven't found any emails.

Comment: Could it be something like an e-mail sending limit? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/manage-sending-quotas-request-increase.html